# Select every record in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, resultset

Is there any easy way to select every record for two tables, kind of hard to explain but if I have two tables Client and Product

```
Client
A
B
C

Product
1
2
3
```

What query would get a result like this:

```
RESULT
A1
A2
A3
B1
B2
B3
C1
C2
C3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's called a `cross join` (or a cartesian product):

```
select c.field, p.field
from client c 
    cross join product p
```

It's fairly straight-forward to combine the columns together at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Use `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT C.client_column
       + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), P.Product_column)
FROM   client C
       CROSS JOIN product P
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`CROSS JOIN`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT C.Name + CAST(P.Id AS VARCHAR(10)) FROM Client C
CROSS JOIN Product P
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, in SQL Server, you can `select` from a column separated list of tables. You can then specify `join` conditions in the `where` clause, which simulates a standard `join`, or you can not specify any `join` conditions, which will create a cartesian product similar to a `cross join`:

```
-- load test data
declare @Client table(Client char(1))
insert into @Client values('A'),('B'),('C')
declare @Product table(Product int)
insert into @Product values(1),(2),(3)

-- return cartesian product
select Client + cast(Product as char(1)) as RESULT
from Client,Product
```